# how to count checked and unchecked in checkbox in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

i just want the number of checked values of checkbox if checked but terribly i spent lots of hour and did not succeed. This is my HTML

```
<table>
<tbody><tr><th>Subscription</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">Jan</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">feb</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">march</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">apr</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">may</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">jun</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">july</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">aug</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">sep</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">oct</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">nov</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month">dec</td></tr>
<tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month" id="subscription_month" onclick="checkedAll2();">select all/unselect all</th></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

now i am trying to do this with javascript and did not get any response, see code

```
function checkedAll2() {
    var aa =  document.getElementsByName("subscription_month");
    checked = document.getElementById('subscription_month').checked;    

    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++) 
    {
        aa[i].checked = checked;
    }

     var numberOfChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
     alert("fgfgf");
var totalCheckboxes = $('input:checkbox').length;
var numberNotChecked = totalCheckboxes - numberOfChecked;
 }
```

I just want how many item in checkbox is **checked in numeric counting only**. **Is it possible through php?.**
please if possible give me any solution...thank in advance..

Comment: Use multiple select instead of checkboxes.

Comment: $('input:checkbox:checked').length; should be $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

Comment: You mention trying this n both JavaScript and PHP. Do you want the count to be computed on the client's browser before they submit or on the server afterwards?

Comment: As a tip: look at `var_dump($_REQUEST)` or `print_r($_REQUEST)` (`$_POST` or `$_GET`) to see what's getting submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.do').on('click',function(){

var checked_num = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);

});
```

and for php if the above is part of a form then the data gets submitted automatically 
u can use $_POST or $_GET depending on ur method and the checkbox name would have been served but u need to change the name of the checkboxes , all cant have the same name. for radio type its fine...use something like subscription_month[] for the checkbox names and they will be given to php in an array

Here a fiddle for the js part

http://jsfiddle.net/TKCah/

Comment: @Amy seriously? You wanted a php solution and you are checking a JS answer as correct? Please consider editing your question

Answer (score 5):

The checkbox values are returned in an array, simply use `count()` to count the checked values.

```
echo count($_POST['subscription_month']);
//This will return the number of checkboxes checked
```

For uncheck, you can simply negate the `count()` returned values from total values.

Also make sure you use `subscription_month[]` for name.

Comment: it is showing only 1 if checked any number of checkbox

Comment: @Amy did you made the name in html like this? `subscription_month[]`

Comment: did, but prblm same....... :(

Comment: @Amy no way it won't work ... it should...

Answer (score 1):

make checkbox an `array` like below

```
<table>
<tbody><tr><th>Subscription</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">Jan</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">feb</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">march</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">apr</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">may</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">jun</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">july</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">aug</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">sep</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">oct</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">nov</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]">dec</td></tr>
<tr><th><input type="checkbox" name="subscription_month[]" id="subscription_month" onclick="checkedAll2();">select all/unselect all</th></tr>
```

then simply count the checked checkbox value

```
echo count($_POST['subscription_month']);
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

With php posting these counts with ajax you can check with `count` function

Answer (score -1):

Try this JavaScript (requires jQuery):

```
function countChecked() {
    var checked = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    alert(checked);
}

$("input").on("click", function() {
    countChecked();
});
```